# Reference to method with .apply

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

I have a List called "racers" of simple class

```java
class Racer {
    private String name; 
    private String teamName;
    // and getters
}
```

I am using а method to find maximum lengths of the fields in the list:

```java
int maxRacerNameLength = getMaxFieldLength(racers, Racer::getName);
int maxTeamNameLength = getMaxFieldLength(racers, Racer::getTeamName);
```

Method implementation:

```
private int getMaxFieldLength(List<Racer> racers, Function<Racer, String> getter) {
    return racers.stream().mapToInt(racer -> getter.apply(racer).length()).max().getAsInt();
}
```

How do I get rid of this last lambda using method reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by breaking `mapToInt(racer->getter.apply(racer).length())` into two steps:

```
return racers.stream().map(getter::apply).mapToInt(String::length).max().getAsInt();
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Racer> racers = List.of(
                                        new Racer("Andy", "One"), 
                                        new Racer("Thomas", "Four"), 
                                        new Racer("John", "One"),
                                        new Racer("Newton", "Four")
                                    );

        System.out.println(getMaxFieldLength(racers, Racer::getName));
        System.out.println(getMaxFieldLength(racers, Racer::getTeamName));
    }

    static int getMaxFieldLength(List<Racer> racers, Function<Racer, String> getter) {
        return racers.stream().map(getter::apply).mapToInt(String::length).max().getAsInt();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
6
4
```

### Kinds of Method References:

| Kind | Example |
| --- | --- |
| Reference to a static method | ContainingClass::staticMethodName |
| Reference to an instance method of a particular object | containingObject::instanceMethodName |
| Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type | ContainingType::methodName |
| Reference to a constructor | ClassName::new |

Learn more about it from **[Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want as follows:

```java
private int getMaxFieldLength(List<Racer> racers, Function<Racer, String> getter) {
    return racers.stream()
                 .map(getter)
                 .mapToInt(String::length)
                 .max()
                 .getAsInt();
}
```

---

However, I wouldn't recommend getting the value of `OptionalInt` using `getAsInt`.  That's a slippery slope. The list of racers might be empty, that will cause `NoSuchElementException`.

You should either return a default value in that case (0 seems fine here):

```java
private int getMaxFieldLength(List<Racer> racers, Function<Racer, String> getter) {
    return racers.stream()
                 .map(getter)
                 .mapToInt(String::length)
                 .max()
                 .orElse(0);
}
```

or return `OptionalInt` and let the method caller deal with it:

```java
private OptionalInt getMaxFieldLength(List<Racer> racers, Function<Racer, String> getter) {
    return racers.stream()
                 .map(getter)
                 .mapToInt(String::length)
                 .max();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the implementation is bound to always find the max of a Stream of `int`egers, you could rather prefer a [`ToIntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) over a `Function<Racer, String>`. This would change the implementation and signature of the method to:

```
private int getMaxFieldLength(List<Racer> racers, ToIntFunction<Racer> toLength) {
    return racers.stream()
            .mapToInt(toLength)
            .max()
            .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE); // or throw exception for empty racers
}
```

This would in turn the usage of the method to something like:

```
int maxRacerNameLength = getMaxFieldLength(racers, racer -> racer.getName().length());
int maxTeamNameLength = getMaxFieldLength(racers,racer -> racer.getTeamName().length());
```